# Set property on ItemTemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm able to set Margin property on PivotItem when it is declared as:

```
<phone:Pivot Margin="50,0,50,0">
    <phone:PivotItem Margin="0">
        <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
    </phone:PivotItem>
</phone:Pivot>
```

But how do I set Margin when I use binding:

```
<phone:Pivot Margin="50,0,50,0">
    <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>                    
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</phone:Pivot>
```

How do I set Margin on DataTemplate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using style as follow :

```
<phone:Pivot Margin="50,0,50,0">
    <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>                    
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    <phone:Pivot.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="phone:PivotItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </phone:Pivot.ItemContainerStyle>
</phone:Pivot>
```